# How to convert a column into row in sql query usnig pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Using the query `select Size,ColorName,QNTY from tbl1`.

I'm getting following  table

[image]

Now I want to get the table in following format

[image]

How  it possible using pivot

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Size, ColorName, Qnty
      FROM YourTable)p
      PIVOT (SUM(Qnty) FOR Size IN ([34],[32],[30])Pvt
```

In order to have dynamic pivot use following query:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(1000) = '',
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ',['+Size+']'
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Size FROM YourTable)z
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


SET @sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT Size, ColorName, Qnty
                  FROM YourTable)p
            PIVOT (SUM(Qnty) FOR Size IN ('+@columns+')Pvt'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Comment: But it is ([34],[32],[30]) not a fixed range it may be changed it may be [34],[32],[30],[28],[20]

Comment: Your second query is appropriate for me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de1f7/4)**

**Mathod 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT Size, ColorName, Qnty
  FROM Table1
)p
PIVOT 
(
 Max(Qnty) 
 FOR Size IN ([34],[32],[30])
)Pvt
```

**Method 2:**

```
DECLARE @QuestionList nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max);

SELECT @QuestionList = STUFF((SELECT ',['+ CAST(Size AS nVarchar(max))+']'
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Size FROM Table1)z
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ColorName, Qnty, Size FROM Table1
            )X PIVOT (MAX(Qnty) FOR Size IN (' + @QuestionList + ')) pvt
            ORDER BY Colorname;';

Exec sp_executesql @qry;
```

**Method 3:**

```
SELECT ColorName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Size = 34 THEN Qnty END) AS [34],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Size = 32 THEN Qnty END) AS [32],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Size = 30 THEN Qnty END) AS [30]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ColorName;
```